# How do I investigate cause for jenkins build abort by anonymous

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, build-automation

Some of my jenkins build fail randomly and the only clue in the console output I have is:

```
Build was aborted
Aborted by anonymous
```

How do investigate what is the cause of this?

Comment: You can't. By virtue of the fact that anonymous, could have been anybody. Lock down + secure your Jenkins - it is best practices, and gives you traceability + auditing.

Answer (score 12):

If this is happening while running a Multijob using "Multijob Plugin", you need to configure the jobs not to kill the other jobs when they fail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Step1

Make sure you have [Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Authorization+Strategy+Plugin) installed in your jenkins

#### Step2

Go to your job configuration page, set the job with limited access to only some members(like foo, bar), and remove the `build` access for anonymous.
[image]

Comment: The option selected is "logged in users can do anything"  part of the help comment of this selection it says "The only user who won't have full control is anonymous user, who only gets read access".  I think this message is masking another infra-structure error rather than anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

We have upgraded to debian 8 which seams to have solved this. I am not sure if this was related to the JDK we were using simply because other problems we were also seeing such as JDK value set to null error. I have noticed on jenkins own bug launchpad similar problems are ignored because of lack of data. and in my case I do not disagree either, there is lack of data on my problem too.